# Como setar um elemento via jQuery/Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

> Estou fazendo uma integração com um plugin social e estou tendo um problema.

**Meu código:**

```
linkedin : function(self){
  var sett = self.options.buttons.linkedin;
  $(self.element).find('.buttons').append('<div class="button linkedin"><script type="IN/Share" data-url="'+(sett.url !== '' ? sett.url : self.options.url)+'" data-counter="'+sett.counter+'"></script></div>');
  var loading = 0;
  if(typeof window.IN === 'undefined' && loading == 0){
    loading = 1;
    (function() {
      var li = document.createElement('script');li.type = 'text/javascript';li.async = true;
      li.src = '//platform.linkedin.com/in.js'; 
      var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];s.parentNode.insertBefore(li, s);
    })();
  }
  else{
    window.IN.init();
  }
},
```

**O código acima é responsável por criar algo como:**

```
<script src="//platform.linkedin.com/in.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="IN/Share" data-counter="top"></script>
```

**Mas preciso que ele crie igual acima, porém, adicionando** `lang: pt-BR` **antes do** `</script>` **no script puxado do linkedin.**

Assim:

```
<script src="//platform.linkedin.com/in.js" type="text/javascript">
      lang: pt_BR
</script>
<script type="IN/Share" data-counter="top"></script>
```

> Seria possível essa adaptação? como?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Defina o que está dentro como o `innerHTML` (ou `textContent`) da tag:

```
li.innerHTML = 'lang: pt_BR';
```

Comment: Perfeito! Agora está em Português meu widget :D

Comment: Ok @ramaral, obrigado pelo feedback.

Answer (score 1):

Não que seja realmente necessário mas já que foi perguntado a resolução do problema com JavaScript puro ou também com a jQuery e vou ser bem pé-da-letra e deixar a alternativa aqui também

```js
$( document ).ready( function() {
    
    $( '#div' ).append(

        $( '<script>' ).attr({

          'type':  'text/javascript',
          'src':   '//platform.linkedin.com/in.js',
          'async': 'true'

        }).text( 'lang: pt_BR' )
    )

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="div"></div>
```

> É preciso Inspecionar o elemento e procurar a DIV #div para ver, já que é uma tag `<script>`